# Specify language or filetype for "go to symbol" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I work on a solution having both TypeScript and C# files.
It's nice that the Go To Symbol command works on TypeScript, but sometimes I only want to search only for C# members.

**Is there a way to "*Go To Symbol*" with only C# symbols?**

Comment: It looks like it should be supported. Do you have a C# extension installed as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

Comment: @Corné Thanks but I am asking about Visual Studio rather than Visual Studio Code

Comment: Sorry about that - Miss read the title.